# Adding column values of 2 or more non distinct rows. SQL

Tags: php, sql, mysqli, sum

I have a table with the following scheme: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zH2zz.png 
This table is for a hockey league [(Link Here)](http://www.ecmayhem.com/stats2.php). This is the second season where stats will be held in a database. If you look select the dropdowns in the link, you will see that I can produce a top 20 lists for both seasons (1 season has no data yet other than 1 tester). The goal is to total the two seasons and have a All Time top 20 list. I have tried using a sum function, but that literally added every single row into 1.

I only want to sum the rows of repeated player id's. For example, I am player id #2 and I need every goal and assist added per row containing my PID, but I need this for all the top 20 players in 1 query. Here are some of the queries I am using thus far.

```
SELECT Rosters.PID, Rosters.Goals, Rosters.Assists, Rosters.PIM, Rosters.Num, Rosters.TID, Players.pid, Players.firstname, Players.lastname,
      (Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists) AS Points
      FROM Rosters
      INNER JOIN Players
      ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
      WHERE Rosters.TID BETWEEN $parameter
      ORDER BY Points DESC, Goals DESC
      LIMIT 0,20
```

The `$parameter` is based on the team id (TID) There are 16 tid's (8 for each season). This query gets all of the records when the parameter is 1-16, it just doesn't add up non distinct rows by PID (This is ultimately what I would like to learn to do). This is the drop down showing how the query is being instantiated

```
<div class="ddstyle">
    <select name="DropDownTeams" id="DDTeams">
        <option>Select a Season</option>
        <option value="stats2.php?tid=9 AND 16">2015-2016</option>
        <option value="stats2.php?tid=1 AND 8">2014-2015</option>
        <option value="stats2.php?tid=1 AND 16">All Time</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I tried to do:

```
SELECT Rosters.PID, SUM( Rosters.Goals ) Goals, SUM( Rosters.Assists ) Assists, SUM( Rosters.PIM ) PIM, Rosters.Num, Rosters.TID, Players.pid, Players.firstname, Players.lastname, 
    SUM((Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists)) AS Points
    FROM Rosters
    INNER JOIN Players
    ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
    WHERE Rosters.TID BETWEEN 1 AND 16
    ORDER BY Points DESC, Goals DESC
    LIMIT 0,20;
```

But that just added up every record into a single row. The Where clause obviously is not working the way I want when used with the SUM() functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include the `Group BY` section http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

```
SELECT Rosters.PID
    ,SUM(Rosters.Goals) Goals
    ,SUM(Rosters.Assists) Assists
    ,SUM(Rosters.PIM) PIM
    ,Players.pid
    ,SUM((Rosters.Goals + Rosters.Assists)) AS Points
FROM Rosters
INNER JOIN Players ON Rosters.PID = Players.pid
WHERE Rosters.TID BETWEEN 1
        AND 16
GROUP BY 
    Players.pid
ORDER BY Points DESC
    ,Goals DESC 
LIMIT 0
    ,20;
```

Comment: I just gave it a shot, but it did not add up the repeated PID's. I am 19 goals 14 assists in 2014. I have 2 assists in 2015. It should be 19 goals and 16 assists for All time.

Comment: The thing is very hard to try without real data. Can you prepare your schema in http://sqlfiddle.com/ ?

Comment: Yeah, I have never done that before though, so it may take me a bit.

Comment: Use the option `text to ddl`  to easy create tables http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5c2bd/3, I update my question with only `PID`, please try it

Comment: The database was too large

Comment: I did now. Boom goes the dynamite! Thank you = )

Comment: `Boom goes the dynamite!` funny thing I hear today, where are you from ?

Comment: Upstate New York you?

Comment: Venezuela, first time hear that. Be carefull and you trigger an alert on NSA or FBI :P

Comment: Yeah, it is a figure of speech in America. Hopefully the NSA knows better =)...."Boom goes the dynamite" has been used in a large number of television shows, movies and video games, as well as occasionally in theater, advertisements and songs, most frequently between 2008 and 2011. The line is usually used to indicate a pivotal moment."

Comment: Here it is in action. Once I get the stats for the other 100 players into the DB it is going to be really cool! http://www.ecmayhem.com/stats.php?tid=1%20AND%2016